# How to add WYSIWYG editor in Phpfox and how to use it?

Tags: wysiwyg, phpfox

I am using phpfox cms and it have default tiny_mce editor but i want to user WYSIWYG editor, please tell me how can i apply WYSIWYG editor in my code?

Comment: Please tell me what should i do?

Comment: TinyMCE is a WYSIWYG editor, so what is your question?

Comment: I mean, i want to use a editor like CodeMirror to change TinyMCE in phpfox, but i don't know how to do it?.Sorry, my English skill not good.@Tristan

Comment: https://codemirror.net/index.html#description i want to use code mirror editor in phpfox. Please tell me if you have any ideas.